# FFMpeg: Remove duplicate frames AND maintain interlaced field order

Tags: video, ffmpeg, duplicates, frame, frames

I have a video file that contains duplicate frames every 2-3 seconds.

I was able to remove those redundant frames with the following command line:

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB out.mp4

However, at the same time the video was also transcoded into a progressive clip rather interlaced (just like the original file).
How can I force FFmpeg to maintain the interlaced structure, while at the same time removing the duplicate frames?

I'm totally new to FFMpeg and have no clue about command lines and all that stuff.
Maybe you could just help me out with the right code?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Share the report after running `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB,idet -report -f null -`

Answer (score 0):

Though this is very specific, here's an idea:

You could try to provide the -ilme option:

> ‘-ilme’ 
>   Force interlacing support in encoder (MPEG-2 and MPEG-4 only).
>   Use this option if your input file is interlaced and you want to keep
>   the interlaced format for minimum losses. The alternative is to
>   deinterlace the input stream with ‘-deinterlace’, but deinterlacing
>   introduces losses.

See also documentation here: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

Comment: So the code would be:

ffmpeg -i Test.mp4 -ilme -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB out_interlaced.mp4

Am I right? But that didn't work. "Unrecognized option '-ilme'"

Comment: When you type "man ffmpeg" and search for "ilme", is the option displayed?